# Typeerror: view.getcontroller

Tags: python, odoo

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 677, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 655, in _tag_template
    return self._tag_record(record)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 580, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 4213, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 4142, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-43>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 482, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_fields.py", line 534, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 3903, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\fields.py", line 1185, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 300, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 500, in write
    res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 3687, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(vals, inverse_fields)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\models.py", line 1266, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 411, in _check_xml
    )).with_traceback(e.__traceback__) from None
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 385, in _check_xml
    view_def = view.read_combined(['arch'])
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 809, in read_combined
    arch = root.apply_view_inheritance(arch_tree, self.model)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 750, in apply_view_inheritance
    return self._apply_view_inheritance(source, inherit_tree)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 758, in _apply_view_inheritance
    source = view.apply_inheritance_specs(source, arch_tree)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 735, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.handle_view_error(str(e))
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 673, in handle_view_error
    raise ValueError(formatted_message).with_traceback(from_traceback) from from_exception
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: Error while validating view:

Element '<xpath expr="//script[last()]">' cannot be located in parent view

View name: QUnit Assets
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(1033,)
 xmlid: qunit_suite
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(199,)
 file: f:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\custom\muk_web_utils\template\assets.xml


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 684, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 348, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 913, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 532, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "f:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1393, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "f:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1381, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-72>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 475, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 593, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 460, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 348, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 221, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 69, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 733, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 799, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 719, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 685, in _tag_root
    )) from e
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 640, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "F:\odoo-14.0\odoo-14.0\odoo\http.py", line 316, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing None:73, near
<data name="QUnit Assets" inherit_id="web.qunit_suite">
        <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/muk_web_utils/static/tests/fields.js"/>
        </xpath>
    </data>

and here is my code:
/**********************************************************************************
*
*    Copyright (c) 2017-2019 MuK IT GmbH.
*
*    This file is part of MuK Web Utils 
*    (see https://mukit.at).
*
*    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
*    it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
*    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
*    (at your option) any later version.
*
*    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*    GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
*
*    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
*    along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*
**********************************************************************************/
odoo.define('muk_web_utils.tests.fields', function (require) {
"use strict";

var basicFields = require('web.basic_fields');
var concurrency = require('web.concurrency');
var config = require('web.config');
var core = require('web.core');
var FormView = require('web.FormView');
var KanbanView = require('web.KanbanView');
var ListView = require('web.ListView');
var session = require('web.session');
var testUtils = require('web.test_utils');
var field_registry = require('web.field_registry');

var createView = testUtils.createView;
var createAsyncView = testUtils.createAsyncView;
var DebouncedField = basicFields.DebouncedField;
var JournalDashboardGraph = basicFields.JournalDashboardGraph;
var _t = core._t;

QUnit.module('muk_web_utils', {}, function () {

QUnit.module('fields', {
    beforeEach: function () {
        this.data = {
            partner: {
                fields: {
                    display_name: {
                        string: "Displayed name",
                        type: "char",
                        searchable: true
                    },
                    short: {
                        string: "Short",
                        type: "char",
                        searchable: true,
                        trim: true
                    },
                    long: {
                        String: "Long",
                        string: "txt",
                        type: "text",
                    },
                    document: {
                        string: "Binary", 
                        type: "binary",
                        attachment: true,
                    },
                },
                records: [{
                    id: 1,
                    display_name: "first record",
                    short: "Short Text",
                    long: "Super looooooong Text",
                    document: 'coucou==\n',
                }],
            },
        };
    }
}, function () {
    QUnit.module('BinaryFileCopy');

    QUnit.test('Fields is correctly rendered', function (assert) {
        assert.expect(2);

        var form = createView({
            View: FormView,
            model: 'partner',
            data: this.data,
            arch: (
                '<form string="Partners">' +
                    '<field name="document" widget="copy_binary" filename="short"/>' +
                    '<field name="short"/>' +
                '</form>'
            ),
            res_id: 1,
        });

        assert.strictEqual(
            form.$('a.o_field_widget[name="document"] > .mk_copy_binary > .mk_copy_button').length, 
            1, "the copy button should be visible in readonly mode"
        );

        form.$buttons.find('.o_form_button_edit').click();

        assert.strictEqual(
            form.$('a.o_field_widget[name="document"] > .mk_copy_binary').length, 
            0, "the copy button shouldn't be visible in edit mode"
        );
        
        form.destroy();
    });
    
    QUnit.module('CharShare');

    QUnit.test('Fields is correctly rendered', function (assert) {
        assert.expect(1);

        var form = createView({
            View: FormView,
            model: 'partner',
            data: this.data,
            arch: (
                '<form string="Partners">' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<field name="short" widget="share_char"/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</form>'
            ),
            res_id: 1,
        });

        assert.strictEqual(
            form.$('span.o_field_widget[name="short"] > .mk_share_dropdown.mk_share_char').length, 
            1, "the copy button should be visible in readonly mode"
        );
        
        form.destroy();
    });
    
    QUnit.module('TextShare');

    QUnit.test('Fields is correctly rendered', function (assert) {
        assert.expect(1);

        var form = createView({
            View: FormView,
            model: 'partner',
            data: this.data,
            arch: (
                '<form string="Partners">' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<field name="long" widget="share_text"/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</form>'
            ),
            res_id: 1,
        });

        assert.strictEqual(
            form.$('span.o_field_widget[name="long"] > .mk_share_dropdown.mk_share_text').length, 
            1, "the copy button should be visible in readonly mode"
        );
        
        form.destroy();
    });
    
    QUnit.module('BinaryFileShare');

    QUnit.test('Fields is correctly rendered', function (assert) {
        assert.expect(2);

        var form = createView({
            View: FormView,
            model: 'partner',
            data: this.data,
            arch: (
                '<form string="Partners">' +
                    '<field name="document" widget="share_binary" filename="short"/>' +
                    '<field name="short"/>' +
                '</form>'
            ),
            res_id: 1,
        });

        assert.strictEqual(
            form.$('a.o_field_widget[name="document"] > .mk_share_dropdown > .mk_share_button').length, 
            1, "the share dropdown should be visible in readonly mode"
        );

        form.$buttons.find('.o_form_button_edit').click();

        assert.strictEqual(
            form.$('a.o_field_widget[name="document"] > .mk_share_dropdown > .mk_share_button').length, 
            0, "the share dropdown shouldn't be visible in edit mode"
        );
        
        form.destroy();
    });
});

});

});
```

When i upgrade this module from odoo 12 to odoo 14 then this error occured.When I changed the xpath and install this module its show an error typerror:view.getcontroller(....)then.guardedcatch is not a function. I have no idea about this error how can i fix it and in my code where i need to change please help me.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
```

Odoo can't able to get the above expr path so please check your **inherited_id** in v14.

or try to rewrite as this:

```
<template id="qunit_suite" name="QUnit Assets" inherit_id="web.qunit_suite">
    <xpath expr="//script[last()]" position="after">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/muk_web_utils/static/tests/fields.js" />
    </xpath>
</template>
```